# What data structure is similar to that of a database?

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures, f#

What is a data structure (like list, array, etc...) that could replace a database like SQL?

I would like it to have as many database-like features as possible, like query select and so on...

If is there none, suggest structure how it should be look like

edit:

datatable is good enough i think, thx for the answers

Comment: What language? Are you wanting to be able to query stuff in memory rather than from a database?

Comment: In C# there is the entity framework that has classes representing database objects for example

Comment: C# F# ,both are great, Troy Turley yeah, Nigel how it called ?

Comment: Write an interface with the methods that you want. That interface will describe how you want to interact with this unspecified thing. Two things will happen: 1) You'll have a clearer understanding of what you want to do, 2) other people will be able to understand it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest such data structure would be a `record` in F# or a `class` in C#. This would represent your table. A collection of tables would represent a database. You can query this with [query expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) (aka Linq), and serialize  it as pointed out above. You can also use a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/datatables). If you are just looking for an in memory representation of a database you could have that with `SQLite`.

If you just want to access a database you can do it with the SQLProvider in F#, or Dapper in both F# and C#.

Here is an example with a list of records and a query expression:

```
open System

type Row = {
    Id: bigint
    Name: string
    Address: string
}

let table = [
    {Id = 100I; Name = "Joe"; Address = "NYC"}
    {Id = 101I; Name = "Jane"; Address = "KC"}
    {Id = 102I; Name = "Jim"; Address = "LA"}
]

let notInNYC = 
    query {
        for user in table do
            where (user.Address <> "NYC")
            select user.Name
    }   
    |> Seq.toList
//val notInNYC : string list = ["Jane"; "Jim"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know about [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) as an ORM and a gateway to access DBs, here are some alternatives you'd want to have in mind.

**One** straight forward and quick solution for small data amounts is [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/).

You can choose from:

- [Json](http://json.net)
- [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization)
- [Binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization)
- Some others.

Serialization allows you to store and retrieve an object graph with not fuss of setting up DBs and connections. But doesn't give sophisticated search and update capabilities.

**Another thing** you might want to explore is [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases.

Check out [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org) to get you started with the concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use an actual SQL database, then
(per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection#Examples)):

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If you are looking to not use an actual SQL database and try to save data, relations, etc. directly in your code (not sure why you'd want to do that), you could create your own custom classes for it. You'd want to include some form of table, as well as a search method that could look through the instances of table, etc. There are so many functionalities that you'd have to implement though, so this would be difficult to do if you are trying to replicate all of the functionality of a real SQL db.